# How to continue adding more json info

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making `http` requests in order to retrieve `json` values in a loop like this:

```
while response.status_code == 200:
   response = requests.get(link)
   data = response.json()
   # doing stuff
```

and what data looks like:

```
[
 {
  'A': 'foo',
  'B': 'faa',
  'C': 'fee'
 }
]
```

I just want to append the `n` request below the `n-1` and so on, but with this I'm only saving the values of the last request.

This is an example of what I want, after making the second request:

```
[
 {
  'A': 'foo',
  'B': 'faa',
  'C': 'fee'
 },

 {
  'A2': 'foo2',
  'B2': 'faa2',
  'C2': 'fee2'
 }

]
```

- How can I achieve this?
- Is there any better way to save the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a list from outside the loop

```
all_jsons = []
while response.status_code == 200:
   response = requests.get(link)
   all_jsons.append(response.json())
print(all_jsons)
```

Output

```
[{'A': 'foo', 'B': 'faa', 'C': 'fee'}, {'A2': 'foo2', 'B2': 'faa2', 'C2': 'fee2'}, {'A': 'foo', 'B': 'faa', 'C': 'fee'}]
```

Since the response is a list of JSONs objects you can aggregate them into a list that is created outside the loop scope.

Comment: Well, I'm ashamed I couldn't find out by my own this answer. It makes perfectly sense, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. If this is the answer to your question It will be highly appreciated if you can vote and mark the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is! It's just it can be selected within teh first 10 minutes, but don't worry, I'll select it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, happy to assist.